# A record with zerigo DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, zerigo

I host my domain in Zerigo's DNS service, the domains A-record points to EC2 instance. I guess I dont need bind in EC2 server, just handle domains with apache virtualhost, this is right? Can I handle subdomain's (lorem.ipsum.com) A-record with apache virtualhost?

Comment: Yes you can....

Answer (score 0):

You don't need BIND on the EC2 server, if you already have an external DNS service.

Apache virtualhosts are independent from DNS. To setup a new website, all you need to do is:

1. you go to your DNS provider. You add your subdomain (lorem.ipsum.com) as "A" record mapping to the IP address of your EC2 apache server
2. you go to Apache. You set up a virtual host for "lorem.ipsum.com"